# How can i use multiple JSON files, into a Thread Group /(bzm - Concurrency Thread Group) of Jmeter 5.1.1, to do a concurrent testing?

Tags: json, testing, concurrency, jmeter

using Jmeter 5.1.1, I want to do a concurrent testing.
I use "Thread Group" or "bzm - Concurrency Thread Group" into a "Test Plan" of Jemter.
I have to use multiple JSON files.
so i created multiple HTTP requests and input JSON files into them.
[my Jmeter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpBEl.png)
[multiple JSON files are into multiple HTTP requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqBsG.png)

Is it a Concurrent Testing?

How can I use multiple JSON files into a HTTP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add multiple "Thread Group" into a "Test Plan". Inside "Test Plan"  Unselect "Run thread groups consecutively".

Inside every "Thread Group" configure "Number of Threads(users)" as "1",  "Ramp-Up Period" as "0", "Loop Count" as "1".

Now, add  "HTTP Request" into each "Thread Group". Every "HTTP Request" you can add your "JSON file" and configure the "URL". 
Configure all the "HTTP Request" according to this.

Now add "View Results Tree" as a listener into a "Test Plan". 
Now run the Test plan.

[example of using multiple JSON files to do a concurrent testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzihn.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario JMeter will kick off 3 threads in 1 second and let them run for another second. The number [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers which will be executed will depend on your application response time. If 3 virtual users running requests for 1 second is what you call "concurrent testing" then yes. You can always check how many virtual users were online during each test phase using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener.

Looking into the structure of your requests you can achieve the same by using a single HTTP Request sampler, JMeter offers a number of [functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which can be used for parameterization, for example you can use:

- [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function as `createdDate`
- [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function as `Id`
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function as `LastName` and/or `Title`

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.